# ExpressJS jQuery ajax Post returns nothing

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, express

I'm trying to return some values from Ajax post request, but I don't see any values in console. What's missing here?

Express

```
app.post('/register',function(req,res) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); // it works
    res.send(req.body); // it doesn't work on client side.
});
```

jQuery

```
$("#register").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {};
    data.username = $('#username').val();
    data.email = $('#email').val();
    data.password1 = $('#password1').val();
    data.password2 = $('#password2').val();
    if (data.password1 == data.password2) {
        alert("okay");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '/register',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.username + data.email + data.password1 + data.password2); 
                // nothing returns, why?
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.register-now').after('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> ' +
            'You entered two different passwords. ' +
            '</div>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused, you say

> but I don't see any values in console

but then you say

> console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); // it works

What gives?

Comment: I see. That's a good question and I'm about to head to bed... In Chrome what's going on in the Network dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the terminal instead of the browser console. There's nothing wrong with it; it works.